# pthread_join leads to segmentation fault. why?

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads, segmentation-fault

This code receives a input file with 10 filenames, stores them into an 2d array and creates 10+1 threads: a requester and 10 converters. This is only a skeleton, so my threads only print their id, thei're not accessing any global or shared variable or something that requires a mutex. So, what should I do to avoid a segmentation fault here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define READ_BUFFER_LEN 16
//#define MAX_LENGTH 128

enum {
    MAX_LENGTH = 512
};

typedef struct FileNameArray {
    size_t nfiles; /* Number of file names allocated and in use */
    size_t maxfiles; /* Number of entries allocated in array */
    char **files; /* Array of file names */
} FileNameArray;


//GLOBAL vars
int num_images, *threads_ids /*threads ids*/;
pthread_t *threads;

void deallocate2D(FileNameArray *names) {
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < names->nfiles; i++)
        free(names->files[i]);
    free(names->files);
    names->nfiles = 0;
    names->files = 0;
    names->maxfiles = 0;
}

int readInputFile(FILE *fp, FileNameArray *names) {
    num_images = names->nfiles;
    int max_lines = names->maxfiles;
    char **file_names = names->files;
    char line[MAX_LENGTH];
    char **final_filenames, **array;

    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fp) != NULL) {
        if (line[0] != '\n') {
            /* Remove newline from end of file name */
            char *nl = strchr(line, '\n');
            if (nl != 0)
                *nl = '\0';
            if (num_images >= max_lines) {
                max_lines += 100;
                array = realloc(file_names, max_lines * sizeof (char*));
                if (array == NULL) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Error reallocating space for 2d array: %s\n",
                            strerror(errno));
                    return -1;
                }
                names->maxfiles = max_lines;
                names->files = array;
                file_names = array;
            }
            if ((file_names[num_images] = malloc(strlen(line) + 1)) == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating space for 2d array: %s\n",
                        strerror(errno));
                return -1;
            }
            names->nfiles++;
            strcpy(file_names[num_images], line);
            printf("name of file %d is: %s \n", num_images, file_names[num_images]);
            num_images++;
        }
    }

    printf("Num_lines: %d\n", num_images);
    //realloc to number of lines in the file, to avoid wasting memory
    if ((final_filenames = realloc(file_names, num_images * sizeof (char*))) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reallocating space for 2d array: %s\n",
                strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    names->maxfiles = num_images;
    names->files = final_filenames;
    return 0;
}

void* requester(void* arg) {

    printf("This is the requester thread\n");
    //sleep(1);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return NULL;
}

void* converter(void *id) {
    int my_id = *((int*) id);

    printf("Thread's id is: %d\n", my_id);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FileNameArray names = {0, 0, 0};
    int i, rc;
    pthread_attr_t attr;


    //check parameters
    if (argc < 4) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s input_filename.ppm charWidth charHeight\n",
                argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Opening input file [%s]\n", argv[1]);
    FILE *fpin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (fpin == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open input file %s (%s)\n",
                argv[1], strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    if ((names.files = malloc(10 * sizeof (char*))) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating initial space for 2d array: %s\n",
                strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    names.maxfiles = 10;

    if (readInputFile(fpin, &names) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading image filenames from input\n");
        return -1;
    }

    threads = (pthread_t*) malloc(num_images + 1 * sizeof (pthread_t));
    threads_ids = (int*) malloc(num_images + 1 * sizeof (int));

    /* Initialize and set thread detached attribute */
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
    //creates requester thread, the 1st one on the list
    pthread_create(&threads[0], &attr, requester, &threads_ids[0]);
    threads_ids[0] = 0;

    //creates so many converter threads as the number of images to convert
    for (i = 1; i < num_images + 1; i++) {
        threads_ids[i] = i;
        rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], &attr, converter, &threads_ids[i]);
        if (rc) {
            printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }


    /* Free attribute and wait for the other threads */
    pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);

    for (i = 0; i < num_images + 1; i++) {
        printf("Waiting for thread nr %d\n", i);
        rc = pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
        if (rc) {
            printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_join() is %d\n", rc);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    fclose(fpin);
    free(threads);
    free(threads_ids);
    printf("###########\n");

    deallocate2D(&names);

    printf("Done!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This is one of the possible ouputs:

```
Num_lines: 10
This is the requester thread
Thread's id is: 1
Thread's id is: 2
Thread's id is: 3
Thread's id is: 5
Thread's id is: 4
Thread's id is: 6
Thread's id is: 7
Thread's id is: 8
Thread's id is: 9
Waiting for thread nr 0
Thread's id is: 10
Segmentation fault
```

and this is the result of gdb:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x001bfea9 in *__GI___libc_free (mem=0x804c278) at malloc.c:3724
3724    malloc.c: No such file or directory.
    in malloc.c
(gdb) where
#0  0x001bfea9 in *__GI___libc_free (mem=0x804c278) at malloc.c:3724
#1  0x00120802 in *__GI__dl_deallocate_tls (tcb=<value optimized out>, 
    dealloc_tcb=112) at dl-tls.c:487
#2  0x00133748 in __free_stacks (limit=41943040) at allocatestack.c:274
#3  0x00133849 in queue_stack (pd=0xb5fd9b70) at allocatestack.c:302
#4  __deallocate_stack (pd=0xb5fd9b70) at allocatestack.c:740
#5  0x00134b37 in pthread_join (threadid=3053296496, thread_return=0x0)
    at pthread_join.c:110
#6  0x0804955c in main (argc=4, argv=0xbffff4a4) at main.c:261
```

Comment: Could you point it where line 26 of main.c is?

Comment: Line 261,not 26, is this : rc = pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ```
> threads = (pthread_t*) malloc(num_images + 1 * sizeof (pthread_t));
> threads_ids = (int*) malloc(num_images + 1 * sizeof (int));
> ```

Certainly you must have intended to write

```
threads = malloc((num_images + 1) * sizeof (pthread_t));
threads_ids = malloc((num_images + 1) * sizeof (int));
```

or

```
threads = calloc(num_images + 1, sizeof (pthread_t));
threads_ids = calloc(num_images + 1, sizeof (int));
```

instead?

Comment: @neverMind: Yes, partially, your variables were too small. Multiplication and division always happen before addition and subtraction, just like in regular math. If you need to change the order, you need to add parenthesis.

Comment: But also, don't cast the result of `malloc`. Doing so prevents the compiler from picking up that you haven't properly `#include`d stdlib.h . An implicit cast will happen and is standard and idiomatic C.

Comment: @Karl: It's likely that another header has `#include <stdlib.h>` and @neverMind gets it transitively, but yes, it's bad form both to miss required headers and also to cast void pointers.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know, I always cast things! But this must have been a copy-paste from another bad example of mine, because when I write it from the beginning , usually I don't miss tparentesis order. Thank you

Comment: On the explicit cast from `void *`: if you ever have to compile this with a C++ compiler, you'll just end up throwing the explicit cast back in anyway. It's something worth keeping in mind when making universal declarations that one style is better than another.

Comment: @LnxPrgr3: Would you also say ability to run Perl code with a Ruby interpreter should be a consideration in writing Perl? :-)

Comment: @R..: Which is more likely… compiling C code with a C++ compiler, or running Perl code in a Ruby interpreter? :-P

Comment: @LnxPrgr3: http://shinh.skr.jp/obf/sym_poly_quine.txt Ruby+Perl+JS http://shinh.skr.jp/obf/poly_quine5.txt C+Ruby+Python+Perl+BF ;-)

Comment: I personally find the intersection of C and C++ an extremely ugly language, so for C code written by me at least, the chance of it compiling unmodified as C++ is pretty low. Coupled with the chance of subtle bugs from constructs that compile in both languages but mean slightly different things, I think it's a very misguided practice to write C in the hope that it can also be used as C++. I really have no idea what Ruby looks like and chose it as a random script language, and figured Perl has a million ways of doing any given task so you could probably make it look like most script languages...